# override, virtual/dynamic in Delphi constructors

Tags: delphi, methods, constructor, virtual-functions

The one with virtual/dynamic

```
// declare in Child Class
constructor Create; virtual;

constructor TChildClass.Create;
begin
  inherited;
end;
```

The one with override.

```
// declare in Child Class
constructor Create; override;

constructor TChildClass.Create;
begin
  inherited;
end;
```

The one with nothing

```
// declare in Child Class
constructor Create;

constructor TChildClass.Create;
begin
  inherited;
end;
```

Are these the same thing? It looks confusing.

Comment: Does this Q have anything to do with constructors in particular, or with OOP in general?

Comment: actually, just want to know the difference specific in this delphi example.

Comment: It would be best if you didn't leave guessing games in the question. The "// declare" lines, are those part of the base class or the child class? It would be best if you produced complete, yet minimal examples in each case.

Comment: yes, they are all the constructor in child classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, static and virtual methods are not the same thing.

And `override` is a case of `virtual` method.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Methods#Method_Binding

Constructors bring nothing special here - they conform to the same rules as other methods for the question

Comment: the inherited can be in the constructor no matter what the keywords come after constructor, right?

Comment: Yes. `Inherited` simply calls the ancestor class's method, irrespective of anything in the descendant.

Comment: @Rob: correction: while this is not actual for constructors, in general, `inherited` calls ancestor's method **if there is one** and does nothing (no-op) **if there is none** - that makes difference for `abstract` methods,

Comment: @RobKennedy ....the comment above relates on using `inherited;` keyword as a special kind of instruction on its own merit, in this 'shortcut' case "inherited" statement acts like no-brainer forgiving stub. But `inherited` can also be used as modified to a regular call when followed by some method name like in `inherited Create();` - then the implementation should exist.

Comment: I know. Regardless, my statement that it behaves irrespective of anything in the descendant remains true.

Comment: @RobKennedy I know that you know. But since we are making comments for other readers, i wanted to "publish" this explicitly.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is a difference, but let's deal with the `virtual` keyword in more basic OOP terms first, yet still how it applies to Delphi methods.

When you declare a derived (child) class, and implement a method as "override", it means that you're overriding (surprise) the matching method of the base class.

This means that you can write code like this:

```
var child : TBaseClass;
begin
    child := TChildClass.Create; // note that it is stored in TBaseClass variable
    child.VirtualMethodDefinedInBaseClassThatHasBeenOverriddenInChildClass;
```

This will call the method in the child class, even if the variable is defined to be of the base class type. This is the whole purpose of virtual methods, you can access the object through a reference of a more general type, and still call methods that have been written for the particular type of object you're dealing with.

If you have a virtual method in the base class that you chose not to override in the child class, but instead reintroduce, you're effectively replacing it in some cases. Note that in most cases you need to tell the compiler that you really meant to do this, though I'm unsure about what Delphi requires here.

Basically, if your variable is of type TBaseClass, and you call a virtual method on it, that has been reintroduced in the TChildClass, it will still call the method in the base class.

However, if your variable is of type TChildClass, and you call that method on it, you will get the new method instead.

Now, for constructors, in Delphi, it is slightly different.

The point of virtual constructors is to be able to virtually construct objects, and to do that, Delphi also has "class types".

You can say this:

```
type TClassToUse = class of TBaseClass;
var cls : TClassToUse;
    obj : TBaseClass;
begin
    cls := TChildClass;
    obj := cls.Create;
```

*(note that my Delphi knowledge is a bit rusty here, if anyone spots bugs or glaring problems in the above code, please let me know or just fix it)*

Here we store a "class" in a variable, and then ask the class to please construct an object for us. This allows us to switch out which class to create, but we also need to declare the constructors we want to use virtual, otherwise we will have problems.

So in the above code, if you declared the constructor as virtual in TBaseClass, and then override it in TChildClass (which the code is actually using in `cls`), the overridden constructor is the one that will be used.

If, on the other hand, you don't declare the constructor as virtual, we're back to the base class constructor. Virtual basically means to figure out the right method to execute at runtime, whereas non-virtual will figure it out at compile time.

Reintroduction as described for normal methods above, also works this way.

However, virtual constructors are only used as virtual when used through a class type.

Comment: +1. Nice answer. Just as an FYI: Delphi does indeed include a `reintroduce` keyword for reintroduction, used when defining methods with the same name but different parameters than the one in the parent class.

Comment: Reintroduce is never required, the method in the ancestor is simply hidden. However, not using reintroduce on a method that is virtual (or dynamic) in the ancestor will trigger a warning that "method X is hiding virtual method X in ancestor A" (something along those lines). So if you want your compiles/builds to emit zero hints and warnings (which you should want), then you will need to use reintroduce.

Comment: @MarjanVenema but it better be required.  I guess in early version hiding was considered harmful and dangerous and deserving warnings in any case. When they decided to make it a lawful if exotic practice, they could not enforce it due to backward compatibility...

Comment: @Arioch'The: yes, I would prefer it too if reintroduce was always required. The fact that it isn't can lead to some hard to track down bugs and AV's.